# Capture multiline Python output in C#

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to write a piece of C# code which makes use of a small portion of Python code, and then try to output the Python code within my application. The goal is to have a Python RSS, which produces few lines of data and outputs it.

I hoped that a C# code would execute this code and capture all of the lines that are produced, but it captures only first one.

Here is a sample of what python output looks like:

```
Business    Superjumbo jet future secured by Emirates order. A big order from Emirates airline saves the A380 after Airbus threatened to stop making the plane.
Business    Banks create funds for firms hit by Carillion collapse. Lloyds and RBS will provide cash for struggling small firms as Nationwide takes on Carillion staff.
Politics    Theresa May meets Macron with pledge of extra £44m for border. The UK pledges an extra £44m for channel border security ahead of the Anglo-French summit.
```

This is a short excerpt of the produced data, but C# ( result variable) only captures first line, sometimes two.

**Am I doing something wrong or is not possible to get all prints using this method?**

*C# code*

```
start.Arguments = "../test/smallWebCrawl.py";
start.UseShellExecute = false;// Do not use OS shell
start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
try
{
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
            //Console.WriteLine(stderr);

            string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error. Wrong python path");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find an alternative solution, which works and which I decided to use, although it is not the best, but I was keen on leaving the overall structure of the code, the way it was.

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                    {
                        string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); 

                        process.WaitForExit();

                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        string text = File.ReadAllText(start.WorkingDirectory + "\\t.txt");
```

So basically, I wait for the exit of my Python script to ensure that all data has been written to a file, then read the whole produced text file, which can be later deleted.